# Quantos dias uma sugestão de edição de pergunta fica pendente?

Tags: suporte

Tenho uma proposta de edição de pergunta e tem 52 dias que ela não foi tratada, qual é o prazo para `aprovar` ou `recusar` essas sugestões?

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/422653

Comment: Apesar da pergunta ser sobre edição especificamente, é o mesmo caso da pergunta linkada acima (sugestão de edição também vai para as filas de revisão da comunidade), vide resposta. No caso específico da sua edição, aproveitei para aprovar. Note que no caso, a marcação de código para a palavra build não é adequada, provavelmente isso deve ter deixado os revisores em dúvida quanto a aprovar ou não. Caberia itálico, por se tratar de outro idioma, os backticks são para código, palavras-chave de linguagem etc.

Comment: Boa, referente ao itálico eu não sabia!